# Automatic viewport selection from camera bounds

Tags: 3d-view, camera, selection-tools

I'm working on an animation that requires me to select objects in the camera's viewport and project from view. I was wondering if there's any hotkey or way to scrub through the animation while constantly selecting in the bounds of the camera's view as it would greatly speed up my workflow. Having to move a few frames forward then box selecting is just a bit too tedious.

It might also come in handy later if I need to get rid of geometry that's not visible in my project.

Comment: Is there any way to use the assign hotkey tool?

Comment: I'm not sure, is it even a hotkey I can do that for?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could use the data outliner that shows what objects are in your scene to do this. Is there a reason that you are doing this? Im asking to see if there is a better way to approach this

Comment: I created a large particle field and randomly put cubes and spheres as the render objects then made their instances real, put a camera to fly through it and projection mapped and image onto it to make that perspective illusion where everything just lines up perfectly to create an image. I needed to delete a bunch of them that wouldn't be visible at all during the animation so I box selected the camera viewport every few frames then deleted everything not visible.

Comment: I doubt it, but you might be able to use the camera texture coordinates to help you